# How to upload file using multipart post with multer is nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to upload file using multer. File is not getting uploaded. Pl let me know what is the issue with the code.
As per multer documentation req.body carries file, but its undefined.

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var jade = require('jade');
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/signup', function (req, res){
 res.render('signup');
});

app.post('/signup', upload.single('profile_images'), function(req, res){
 if(req.file){
  console.log(util.inspect(req.file));
 }
 res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
 console.log('Server started');
});
```

```html
html
 head
  title #{title}
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
 body
  h1 #{title}
  p Enter your name and email address to become a member.
  form(action='/signup', method='post', enctype='multipart/formdata')
   div
    label Name
    input(type='text', name='name')
   div
    label Email
    input(type='text', name='email')
   div
    label Profile Image
    input(type='file', name='profile_image')
   div
    input(type='submit')
```

Comment: i see a plural `upload.single('profile_images')` on the server and singular `name='profile_image'` in the form

Comment: In console.log(req.body); What did you get in the console exactly?

Comment: console.log doesn't print anything.

Comment: Josh, it doesn't work after using same name 'profile_images' for both

Comment: @HiteshShahjee check your form attribute of enctype. Pretty sure it needs to be multipart/form-data. The dash should be required.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Issue was with form attribute enctype. After adding dash its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with form attribute enctype. After adding dash (multiparty/form-data), its working fine.

Comment: can you try to explain more what you did exactly : "After adding dash(multiparty/form-data)"  I don't understand. I have same problem the console.log is not showing anything.